# AddFontResource() vs AddFontResourceEx()

Tags: winapi, fonts

As can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the function `AddFontResource()`requires that the app should send a `WM_FONTCHANGE` message to all top level windows in the system, but the [AddFontResourceEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function doesn't require this. Why the difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you normally only use the Ex version to add a private font that no other process can see.  So there's no need to tell anybody about it.

If you don't use the FR_PRIVATE or FR_NOT_ENUM flags then *do* send the message.

Comment: Is it correct to say that, even with `AddFontResource()`, you don't need to send the message, if you don't intend to add the font name and its file to the registry ?